# undefined local variable or method in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application  I  have two tables named coordinates and tweets .To fetch queries the condition is decided in the coordinates controller and executed in the tweets controller. Its basically a tweets search table to fetch matching tweets.  . I am using find_by_sql method.
My Coordinates_controller

```
class CoordinatesController < ApplicationController

  def home 
  end
  # def paramas(b)
  #  
  # @b = params[:show]
  # return @b

  #end
  #def coor(latitude,longitude)
  # @latitude=0
  #@longitude=0
  #end

  def query
    a = Coordinates.where(city: params[:show])
    b = a.first
    if a.count == 1
      latitude = b.latitude
      longitude= b.longitude
    end

    if(latitude=0 && longitude=0) then
      sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND user_loc LIKE 'show' order by id desc LIMIT 30"
    else if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0) 
           min_lat = latitude - 1.0
           max_lat = latitude + 1.0
           min_lng = longitude - 1.0
           max_lng =  longitude + 1.0
           sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE 'show') ) order by id desc LIMIT 30"
         else
           sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%text%' LIMIT 30"
         end    

    end
  end     
  #end


  #end
```

My tweets_controller

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  include CoordinatesHelper
  def search
    render 'tweets/search'
  end


  def index

    # include CoordinatesHelper
   # sql=query
    @tweets=Tweets.find_by_sql(sql)
    #render 'tweets/index'
  end
end
```

The sql variable comes from the coordinates_controller and is decided by the tweets controller.But for some reasons tweets_controller is not recognizing the sql variable inside the coordinates controller. It says "undefined method or local variable sql".Any help is appreciated

Comment: I voted this down because it's sort of clear that you don't really understand Rails very well. I recommend working through one of the many online tutorials if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable `sql` in the `CoordinatesController#query` definition is not visible to anywhere outside of the definition. Even if you make it visible to instances of `CoordinatesController` (by turning it into an instance variable), it will not be visible to `TweetsController`.

Comment: what should I do If I have to make it accessible inside tweets controller?

Comment: That depends on the relation between the two classes. I think you should study the basics of Ruby before proceeding with your Rails project.